# Curve fitting with "rough" loss functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

Many real-valued classification and regression problems can be framed as minimization in the following way.

Setup:

- Let $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be the parameter space that we are searching over.
- For $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ we have nice (smooth, equicontinuous, etc.) $e_i: \Theta \to (0, \infty)$.

  - In practice $e_i$ might represent the absolute prediction error on observation $i$. I exclude 0 because the observation noise is a continuous distribution.
- We have an increasing loss function $\ell: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that "packages" the error in a nice way.

  - In practice $\ell$ is a log-likelihood such as a quadratic for additive Gaussian noise.

Problem:

> Find $\theta \in \Theta$ minimizing the total loss function $f$:
> \begin{align}
>     f(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \ell(e_i(\theta))
> \end{align}

I am wondering how far we can push the regularity of the function $\ell$. On the "nice" side, when $\ell$ is differentiable, the minima of $f$ occur at the boundaries of $\Theta$ or at the critical points of $f$. The problem becomes easier if $\ell$ is convex.

As a lower bound on the regularity of $\ell$, it seems that $\ell$ at least needs to be $L^1_\mathrm{loc}$. Morally, this should mean that if $e_i$ are reasonable random variables, $\mathbb{E}f(\theta) < \infty$.

So this motivates the following ideas for $\ell$:

- $\ell(x) = x$ (1-norm minimization, log loss of Laplace)
- $\ell(x) = \sqrt x$ (log loss of generalized Gaussian with shape $1/2$
- $\ell(x) = \log x$ (log loss of Pareto, for disciples of Nassim Taleb)
- $\ell(x) = -x^{-1/2}$

My questions:

1. What do we know about optimizing rough functions? (theory and numerical)
2. What do we know about the properties of M-estimators when the objective function is non-Lipschitz?